# Is it bad practice to call another API from a Filter?

Tags: java, web-development, rest, web-api

I am using Java, Spring and Jersey.

I have a REST **API A** which receives a query parameter called `q` and sends this to another **API B** to get a response.

I need to implement a change where I first need to pass the query from the client to another **API C** and use the response from **API C** to create a new request, i.e. basically wrap the request in an `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which has the new `q` parameter.

Hopefully this image will clarify this a bit:

[image]

So the idea is to use a `javax.servlet.Filter` for this scenario. Few questions that bug me:

1. Is it good practice to call another API from a `Filter`?
2. I am using Spring. Would it be an issue to use `@Autowired` for the client of **API C** within my `Filter`?

Comment: Why might it be a bad practice?  Does it satisfy your requirements in a way that is maintainable, secure and performant?

Comment: Because I could not find any example where a Filter is used to make calls to another API. And the documentation mention a few basic usages of Filters but nothing like making API2API calls from within a Filter. So I thought this might not be good practice. Any thoughts on my second question? Thanks.

Comment: I would not use filters in this way and I would not modify (never) the incoming request and its parameters. Have you considered AOP? You could set an Advice around the Controllers and make here the changes of the inputs. Spring have two different approaches for AOP. By proxies and by AspectJ.

Comment: @Laiv What is your objection for using Filters for my purpose? Could you elaborate a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Agree with @Laiv, it seems unlikely modifying / replacing the client request in a filter would be maintainable. I'd look to implement this requirement nearer to existing business logic (if possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing what is commonly known as Web Service Orchestration. See [this related post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117570/orchestrating-microservices) about orchestrating micro services.

Using a servlet filter to make a call to an external service is not recommended. According to the Oracle documentation, Filters are supposed to be used to transform the HTTP request or response or both. In this case it is not purely transforming, it is calling an external service which is not under your control, so you need to treat it as a potential failure point.

Filters should be used for transforming formats or logging etc. Put any any external calls should be done in as part of your service orchestration logic.

A limitation of orchestration logic in Filters is that the order in which it called will matter and you will need to be careful to get this order correct. From a code design perspective this make your code more fragile.

Also if you want to later do more complex orchestration of the services with timeouts etc., using filters may be problematic as you may effect other filters in the chain.

Recommended approaches would be use something like Apache Camel or Spring Integration or implement the API Gateway pattern as the above Stack Overflow link suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes it is not good practice because usually we do not need to call external services for each endpoint and orchestration order changes for different use cases, whereas filter is used for common logic around endpoints.

But look what spring [OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/filter/OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html) does, it calls authorization server to fetch tokens.

So it boils down to your requirements, and if you are sure about the order of the external call and you have taken care of service resilience, then there shouldn't be any harm.